# custom wave forms in web audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm working through this awesome article: https://jackschaedler.github.io/circles-sines-signals/dft_introduction.html

I want to use the Web Audio API's PeriodicWave object to implement this demo: [image]

However, when I set a periodic wave with these settings:

```
 var real = new Float32Array([0,0,1,0,1]);
 var imag = new Float32Array(real.length);
 var customWave = context.createPeriodicWave(real,imag);
 osc.setPeriodicWave(customWave);
```

I output a wave that looks like this:

[image]
Here is full code: http://jsbin.com/zaqojavixo/4/edit
To see the waveform, please press play the sound a few times.

I believe these should match up, so here are my questions:

1. Am I missing something fundamental about the theory here or am I just implementing it incorrectly? Is the PeriodicWave object supposed to do the same thing as illustrated in the article?
2. If I am taking the wrong approach, how would I implement this diagram in Web Audio API? I have been able to match below by connecting two different sine waves of different frequencies to the same gain node - how is this different than using the PeriodicWave object?
3. I'm new to DSP and Web Audio API - any suggested reading would be appreciated!
4. Secondarily, in my example, I have to push the 'play the sound' button a couple of times before correct data is drawn to the canvas - the analyser seems to be behind the oscillator, even though analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData() is called after I start the oscillator any thoughts on what's going on here?

---

Edit: As noted in comments, my graph is upside down (on the canvas 0,0 is the upper left corner).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that the first array defines the cosine terms, the second the sine terms:

> The `real` parameter represents an array of **cosine terms** (traditionally
>   the A terms). In audio terminology, the first element (index 0) is the
>   DC-offset of the periodic waveform. The second element (index 1)
>   represents the fundamental frequency. The third element represents the
>   first overtone, and so on. The first element is ignored and
>   implementations must set it to zero internally.
>
> The `imag` parameter represents an array of **sine terms** (traditionally
>   the B terms). The first element (index 0) should be set to zero (and
>   will be ignored) since this term does not exist in the Fourier series.
>   The second element (index 1) represents the fundamental frequency. The
>   third element represents the first overtone, and so on.

[Source](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#methods)

You will see you get the expected waveform but "reversed" (drawn upside down thanks to @Julian for pointing that out in his answer - fixed below):

[image: snap]

(I inlined your code here with the arrays swapped around:)
**updated** fixed drawing issues in original code

```js
//setup audio context
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new window.AudioContext();

//create nodes
var osc; //create in event listener so we can press the button more than once
var masterGain = context.createGain();
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

//routing
masterGain.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

var isPlaying = false;

//draw function for canvas
function drawWave(analyser, ctx) {
  
  var buffer = new Float32Array(1024),
      w = ctx.canvas.width;
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#777";
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,-1,0,100.5); // flip y-axis and translate to center
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  
  (function loop() {
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(buffer);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, -100, w, ctx.canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, buffer[0] * 90);
    for (var x = 2; x < w; x += 2) ctx.lineTo(x, buffer[x] * 90);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    if (isPlaying) requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  })();
}

//button trigger
$(function() {  
  var c = document.getElementById('scope'),
      ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
  c.height = 200;
  c.width = 600;
  
  // make 0-line permanent as background
  ctx.moveTo(0, 100.5);
  ctx.lineTo(c.width, 100.5);
  ctx.stroke();
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + c.toDataURL() + ")";
  
  $('button').on('mousedown', function() {
    osc = context.createOscillator();
    //osc settings
    osc.frequency.value = 220;
    var imag= new Float32Array([0,0,1,0,1]);   // sine
    var real = new Float32Array(imag.length);  // cos
    var customWave = context.createPeriodicWave(real, imag);  // cos,sine
    osc.setPeriodicWave(customWave);

    osc.connect(masterGain);
    osc.start();
    isPlaying = true;
    
    drawWave(analyser, ctx);
  });

  $('button').on('mouseup', function() {
    isPlaying = false;
    osc.stop();
  }); 
});
```

```css
button {position:fixed;left:10px;top:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Play the sound</button>
<canvas id='scope'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this nice renderization of the wave!

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the demo and your output is the phase relationship between the two tones. The demo is `y=sin(x) + sin(2x)` and yours is `y=sin(x) + sin(2x + pi/2)`. It's not apparent to me where this phase shift is coming from but I don't think it's anything you have done.

Here are some plots from wolfram alpha:

[y=sin(x) + sin(2x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%281x%29%20%2B%20sin%282x%29)

[y=sin(x) + sin(2x + pi/2)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%281x%29%20%2B%20sin%282x%2Bpi%2F2%29)

Answer (score 1):

In `createPeriodicWave` the `real` array is the cosine part (or *a* term), while the `imag` array (the *b* term) is the sine part.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series

I think you've just inverted the two. In the article it says:

> Where Ai is the Amplitude of the ith sine and fi is the frequency of
>   the ith sine.

So it's your `imag` array (sine part) that should be [0,0,1,0,1] and your real array should be [0,0,0,0,0].

Like this:

```
var imag = new Float32Array([0,0,1,0,1]);
 var real = new Float32Array(real.length);
```

Try it in your jsbin you'll it works, only thing it'll be inverted because you're drawing in negative (meaning 0 coordinate is the top, not the bottom). To have what's in the article, either draw in reverse or have your imag array like this: [0,0,-1,0,-1].

If you want to play a bit with different `imag` and `real` configuration and see the results, you can see here: http://themusictoolbox.net/waves/